# extract numbers from file names

Tags: bash

I got a lot of files whose names are like this:

```
tmp1.csv
tmp32.csv
tmp9.csv
tmp76.csv
...
```

They are in the same dir, and I want to extract the numbers in the file name. How can I do that in `bash`?

**PS**

I tried `grep`, but can't make it. Also I tried `${filename##[a-z]}`. Are they the right way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in *.csv; do echo $f | egrep -o "[0-9]+" ; done
```

If you have other csv file with digits in their filenames use:

```
for f in *.csv; do echo $f | sed -re 's/^tmp([0-9]+)\.csv$/\1/' ; done
```

Comment: @lukecampbell I disagree that this is canonically correct -- there's no need for grep when bash can do matching internally. Parameter expansion, regexp matching -- it's all built-in, no subprocesses needed. Nothing wrong with this answer, but it's not the only Right Way.

Comment: ...actually, I take that back -- there's plenty wrong with this answer; starting a new echo | grep pipeline per-file is evil.

Comment: @codaddict I'd consider this instead: `printf "%s\n" *.csv | egrep -o '[0-9]+'` -- that way you're only running grep once, instead of once per file.

Comment: Both work but I prefer the grep method. It doesn't mean I'm wrong or right, it's a matter of preference. Unless you can prove that grep has some serious flaw that bash can overcompensate for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Very true. But for a one-off kind of job, I don't think it should matter.

Comment: @codaddict  Can you explain why you chose to echo the filename rather than using `find` or `ls`?  I just want to know for curiosity's sake.

Comment: @lukecampbell "the right way", as you asserted, implies that all other ways are wrong (or, at least, non-cannonical). I don't disagree that this is _a_ right way (once adjusted to avoid the grep-per-file bug), but I very much disagree that it's _the_ right way.

Comment: @TimPote using `ls` would be wrong for the reasons given at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- using `find` would be OK.

Comment: @codaddict maybe it's that I've spent too much time working on servers hosting maildirs with tens of thousands of files in a directory, but I'm accustomed to that kind of thing mattering.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls |grep -o "[0-9]\+"
```

Example:

```
$ ls *.csv
3tmp44.csv  newdata_write.csv  tmp1.csv  tmp2.csv

$ ls *.csv |grep -o "[0-9]\+"
3
44
1
2
```

Edit:

From grep man page:

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> ```
>    In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )  lose  their  special  meaning;  instead  use  the  backslashed
>    versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
> ```

That is why you need to use `\+`

Comment: 2 questions. first, what do you mean by `only get you the first number`? second, why escape `+`?

Comment: @Alcott the escape for the `+` is necessary in Basic RE syntax (as opposed to ERE syntax, as enabled by `egrep` or `grep -E` rather than traditional `grep`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, I `man`ed, but I can't seem to understand what is `ERE`, and why I can't get the right answer with `grep -o "[0-9]+"?

Comment: @Alcott EREs are "extended regular expressions", which are what you're probably used to (basically every modern language or tool uses EREs or PCREs by default rather than old-style Basic REs). In a basic RE, an unquoted `+` matches a literal `+` character, rather than modifying what comes before it. See `man 7 regex`.

Comment: The only big issue with this is its use of `ls`, which creates output intended for human consumption rather than machine consumption. For instance, some versions of ls can print non-ASCII characters as strings like `\003`, and you wouldn't want a file containing such a character to show up in the output as number `003`.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use a couple of invocations of `cut`:

```
$ ls -1 *.csv | cut -dp -f 2 | cut -d. -f1
```

This pipe does:

1. List all files matching the `*.csv` pattern, one per line
2. Use the letter 'p' as the delimiter, and cut out the second field on each line. This transforms e.g. `tmp4711.csv` into `4711.csv`.
3. Use the letter '.' as the delimiter, and cut out the first field on each line. This transforms `4711.csv` into just `4711`, leaving the number isolated and we're done.

Comment: Fragile, particularly in that behavior is undefined with files not matching the tmp###.csv pattern.

Comment: I agree; if you're going to `cut -dp`, you should at least `ls -1 tmp[0-9]*.csv` to mitigate some potential errors.

Answer (score 3):

Easy peasy, using no subprocesses or other tools external to bash itself:

```
for f in *[0-9]*; do
  if [[ $f =~ [0-9]+ ]] ; then
    echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'tmp[0-9]*.csv' | sed 's/tmp\([0-9]\+\).csv/\1/'
```

Comment: Awfully fragile, given that it simply prints any other csv file's name unmodified.